# Idrive integration to fetch video thumbnail and download URL in iOS?

Tags: ios, web-services

How do I fetch video thumbnails and download URL from iDrive API in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with IOS but I believe it has similarities to Linux so the following page may help you get started on writing a script for IOS:

https://idriveusergroup.wordpress.com/file-search/